# powershell script to extract specific column from csv file and store in array

Tags: powershell-3.0

My csv file looks like this

```
Product_Name    Component           SvnDirectory
ABC             export-service      export
ABC             import-service      import
ABC             service-service     service
```

My script should read this file and extract SvnDirectory column and store its values(export, import,service)in an array. I will later be using this to checkout from svn.

The script is

```
$svnDirectory= Import-Csv C:\temp\checkoutdirs.csv | % {$_.SvnDirectory}
Write-host $svnDirectory
```

The problem with this is, it stores values in such a way that I am not able to use it to checkout from svn.

```
Output
@Write-host $svnDirectory
export    import    service
```

So when I try to checkout using this

```
ForEach ($i in $svnDirectory) {
    $checkoutUrl = "$svnRepositoryBase/$svnDirectory/trunk"
    Write-host "SVN url to be checked out is $checkoutUrl"
    java -classpath $env:CLASSPATH org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN co $checkoutUrl --username $username --password $securePassword --non-interactive
}
```

The svn url it takes is

```
SVN url to be checked out is 
http://subversion.abc.com/dev/prj/export  import  service/trunk
```

Comment: I tried this and I get only the svnsubdirectory in the array
 $projectName = import-csv  ABC_Projects.csv | % {$_.SvnDirectory}
 Write-host $projectName

Comment: why do you delete your answer ?

Comment: Your loop is `foreach ($i in $svnDirectory)`, but you're using `$svnDirectory` instead of `$i` to compose `$checkoutUrl `.

Comment: Silly me. Thanks for catching that. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Alright i tried this and it worked

```
 $projectName = import-csv  ABC_Projects.csv | % {$_.SvnDirectory}
 Write-host $projectName
```